# Keras model.fit hangs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, audio-processing

Attempting to fit a Keras model on an `audio_dataset_from_directory` results in the kernel apparently not responding. The following code reproduces my problem (tested in VScode and Jupyter Notebook):

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import pandas as pd
import os

# Create architecture of model
inputs = keras.layers.Input((None, 1))
rnn = keras.layers.SimpleRNN(200)(inputs)
output = keras.layers.Dense(1)(rnn)
# Compile model
model = keras.Model(inputs, output)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error")

# Load data
data = pd.read_csv(".\\files\\metadata.csv", index_col="title")
data = keras.utils.audio_dataset_from_directory(
    ".\\files\\songs", 
    labels=data["UserLikes"].to_list(), 
    label_mode="int", 
    ragged=True, 
    shuffle=True,
)

# Fit model
model.fit(data, epochs=1, verbose=2)
```

In this code, `data["UserLikes"]` (and thus `y` in the Keras dataset) consists of integers in the range [0, inf). An audiofile is processed by Keras as  Tensors of floats of shape (timesteps, channels=1). The total size of the audiofiles is merely 320 MB. The goal of the code is to predict the amount of likes a song gets.

The result of this code is nothing: Everytime I run it, the code gets stuck on `model.fit`. Sometimes the application (i.e., VScode or Jupyter Notebook) even crashes.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this independent of the input file? You should provide at least one file that reproduces this problem with your code. Any error message (full traceback) should also be included in your question.

Comment: maybe OOM? have you tried with a smaller batchsize? are you using M1?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I realize that I have slightly misrepresented the problem: As it turns out, the code is actually running, it just takes so long that the Kernel crashes. This can be seen (among other times) when trying to use the `.predict` method, which takes 160 seconds for one prediction. 
I have tried smaller batches, to no avail.
Perhaps I should open a new issue.